# Gradle Cannot Resolve symbol XmlParser()

Tags: android, gradle, groovy

I have the an implementation in one of my build.gradle files of an Android app that I was using to check some data in the resource file.

```
new XmlParser().parse(stringsFile).string.find { it.@name.equals keyName }.text()
```

This seemed to have been working fine until I decided to upgrade the following

- To API Level 32 from 30
- Gradle from 6.5 to 7.3.

Now I am getting the error 'Cannot find Symbol XmlParser'.

There is no indication of this class being deprecated and I can find it in Groovy documentation. Basically I am trying to read a value from one of the resource xml files in one of the build steps.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since groovy 4 the package for xml classes has been changed from `groovy.util` to `groovy.xml`.

So, now you have to import it differently

```
import groovy.xml.XmlParser
```